# asp.net calling javascript from Code Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, notify

I am using [NOTIFY](http://redeyeoperations.com/plugins/Notify/) on a html input to notify my user whether the record has been saved or not. and It works just fine. But when I try to use it from my code behind file, it isn't. I understand that javascript is a client side technology and have tried using RegisterStartupScript but no luck.

I am trying to use it on a button click like this

```
        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var script = " $.notify.success('I do not want to close by myself close me ', { close: true });";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ButtonAlert", script, true);

    }
```

but no luck.

I am sure there must be a way to show a notification bar on top once the database has been updated. Say can we do it using a function?
my script is defined as follows

```
 <!-- Notify Implementation -->
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Styles/notify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/notify.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     function myNotify() {
         $.notify.success('I do not want to close by myself close me ', { close: true });
     };
```

Can somebody help please

Comment: Pls see browser's console to see if there is any error?

Comment: try to view page source from your browser and see if the script is rendered in there.

Comment: @namkha87 no error thrown

Comment: @IswantoSan i think it is being rendered here is what i found on page source  <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Button1" value="Button" onclick="myNotify();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$Button1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_Button1" />

Answer (score 1):

try like this:-

```
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
                sb.Append("function notify(){");
                sb.Append("$.notify.success('I do not want to close by myself close me ', { close: true });");
    sb.Append("}");
                sb.Append("/script>");

 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ButtonAlert", sb, true);
```

Comment: the browser console throws an exception Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: thats what the chrome console shows only .. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: and this error is thrown on line <script type="text/javascript">function notify(){var script = " $.notify.success('I do not want to close by myself close me ', { close: true });"}</script>//]]>

Comment: bro... my email is aathar at gmail dot com... send me your email addresss i will give you the remote session so that you can check

Comment: please take the remote sharing and see where is the problem. only if you have time

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"ButtonAlert","myNotify()",true);
```

Comment: the browser console throws an exception Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

this resolved my problem as described in [HERE](http://www.emadmokhtar.com/2012/02/using-notification-in-asp-net-webforms/). I used a helper class and yooo it solved the issue.

```
    using System.Web.UI;

public static class NotificationHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the successful notification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public static void ShowSuccessfulNotification(this Page page, string message)
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "notificationScript",
                                                "<script type='text/javascript'>  $(document).ready(function () {  $.notify.success('I do not want to close by myself close me ', { close: true });});</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes... thanks for your help and time bro. i can't mark your answer as solved but would definitely give a up vote. thanks again bro